# Swift: Repeatedly calling a closure passed through identity function causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2

Tags: swift, closures

**Update:**

Here's an even simpler reproduction that doesn't use arrays (h/t to [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231582/tim-bavaro)):

```
func identity<T>(_ v: T) -> T {
    return v
}

var closure = {
    return
}

while true {
    closure()
    closure = identity(closure)
}
```

Running this code causes a stack overflow. I'm filing a bug with Swift.

**Original:**

Original title: Swift: Array of closures causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2

I'm trying to understand why this code produces a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2. Here's the code:

```
var closures: [() -> ()] = []
closures.append({
    return
})

while true {
    var newClosures: [() -> ()] = []
    for closure in closures {
        closure()
        newClosures.append(closure)
    }
    closures = newClosures
}
```

I've tried to distill the problem down to as few lines as possible, which is why the code might seem a little strange and pointless. (Its only "point" is to demonstrate the issue I'm having with as few lines as possible.)

If you run this code in XCode as a macOS console app, you'll see that memory is being allocated without being `free`ed. In Instruments I can see memory is allocated at `newClosures.append(closure)`, which makes sense. What I don't understand is why assigning `closures` to `newClosures` doesn't `free` the old version of `newClosures`. Instead the allocations seem to grow infinitely until I EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2.

It's also worth noting that it doesn't even allocate much memory. In my testing the application crashes after allocating around 17MB (it starts at around 5MB, and ramps up to 17MB in about 60s). So I think it's something to do with the number of objects being retained, rather than the pure size of them.

If I replace the `closures` array with an array to some other reference type, e.g.

```
class Foo { }

var foos: [Foo] = []
foos.append(Foo())

while true {
    var newFoos: [Foo] = []
    for foo in foos {
        newFoos.append(foo)
    }
    foos = newFoos
}
```

It works as expected. I think something must be going on where the closure is capturing more and more stuff every time through the loop? But I don't understand how that could be.

I could probably refactor the code to work around the issue, but at this point I just want to understand what's going on.

Comment: After exploring this for a bit, I am increasingly of the opinion that it's a compiler bug, and you should open a defect at bugs.swift.org. If you run long enough, there's eventually a point where it becomes recursive, and you crash because there are too many thunks and they overflow the stack (look at your stack trace after a few 10k iterations, even before a crash). It's not sensible that this would happen only sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, in my actual program I noticed these really deep stack traces as well. I didn't see them in my test program (I guess I didn't look hard enough), so I didn't mention it. I'll file a bug if no one has an explanation in a few days, I guess.

Comment: I don't know if it helps you at all in your real app, but in the test code, using `append(contentsOf:)` instead of `append(_:)` seems to work without any problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've got a workaround for my application.

Comment: @Andrew I figured it wouldn't help anyway. But you might mention it in your bug report, in case it gives the Swift guys an extra clue.

Comment: Here's the bug I've filed: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Swift. Track the issue here, https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7179.